# WebKit cannot play flash videos after messing in WebKit code

Tags: android, android-ndk, flash

I have application with modified version of android WebKit source code, both java side and native. I am new in project and i do not really know what changes can cause this problem.

When I am creating a mock appliction with default webkit included, flash videos works fine, but when I use modified WebKit instead of default, there is a message than I should install flash player on the device. I am sure that it is installed. Checked it both programaticcaly and manually.

I assume that somebody changed a location where webkit search for adobe flash plugin and this is the reason why it does not work. After days spent on searching in WebKit java and native code I have no idea where the part of code responsible for that is located.

Do you have any ideas or somebody can tell me how webkit deals with adobe flash plugins or how to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best to answer this, as I haven't done it for Android, but on any Linux based system, you need to pass it the resource location for flash player. The default one (on linux) searches common locations until it finds it.